# Animating custom GLTF mesh in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a custom GLTF model I have loaded into my scene, however I'm having trouble positioning and animating the mesh. Currently, I have the mesh's position set to 0,0,0 and have moved the camera position so that the mesh is on the screen when it is loaded, otherwise you would have to pan around to find it. I just changed the camera position slowly until I could finally see it without having to pan the camera. I'm trying to set the default rotation of the mesh, however whenever I change any of the values, the mesh moves really far away and I would have to redo the camera position so that you can see it again. Why does this happen, and is there a way so that once I have the default rotation and position set I can create an animation that just rotates the hand's z-axis   in place without the position changing?

Here's my current code:

```
    import * as THREE from './three.js-master/build/three.module.js'
    import { OrbitControls } from './three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import {GLTFLoader} from './three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      })

    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.enablePan = false;
    controls.enableZoom = false;
    controls.update();

    // const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 6.46, 1.5, 20, 100 );
    // const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xf542d7 } );
    // const torus = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    // scene.add( torus );

    loader.load(
      // resource URL
      './models/hand/hand.gltf',
      // called when the resource is loaded
      function ( gltf ) {

        scene.add( gltf.scene );

        gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
        gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
        gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
        gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
        gltf.asset; // Object

        gltf.scene.children[0].position.set(0,0,0);

      },
      // called while loading is progressing
      function ( xhr ) {

        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

      },
      // called when loading has errors
      function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );

      }
    );

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    directionalLight.position.set(0,0,100)
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    camera.position.set(-300,570,0);


    function animate() {
      // torus.rotation.y += 0.01;
      gltf.scene.children[0].rotation.z += 0.01;
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      controls.update();
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();`
```

I have tried to set the rotation axis separately as well as trying to set an outside variable equal to the gltf.scene.children[0] to rotate it in the animate function.